# I want to set a default column value based on another column and add 114 days to it

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter-table

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás 
    ADD malacozás_ideje AS DATEADD(DAY, 114, Dátum);
```

I want 'malacozás_ideje' column to have the same value as Dátum + 114 days. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a generated column in MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás ADD malacozás_ideje date
    generated always as (Dátum + interval 114 day);
```

If you want to just initialize it:

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás ADD malacozás_ideje date;

UPDATE búgatás
    SET malacozás_ideje date = (Dátum + interval 114 day);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed column instead:

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás ADD malacozás_ideje DATETIME AS (Dátum + INTERVAL 114 DAY);
```

This gives you a virtual column whose value is defined by the computation rule.

On the other hand, if you are looking to create a new column and assigns it new values, that you can later on modify:

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás ADD malacozás_ideje DATETIME;
UPDATE búgatás SET malacozás_ideje  = Dátum + INTERVAL 114 DAY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a computed column that gets computed by default but the syntax you're using is for `SQl Server`. You'll need below for `MySQl`

```
ALTER TABLE búgatás ADD malacozás_ideje GENERATED ALWAYS AS DATE_ADD(Dátum, INTERVAL 114 DAYS);
```